# Forgerock - Forgeops - util - building with RHEL?

Tags: rhel, alpine-linux, openam, rhel7, forgerock

I am trying to take this Dockerfile here - https://github.com/ForgeRock/forgeops/blob/release/6.5.0/docker/util/Dockerfile

And change the old version which is Alpine linux (seen below):

```
FROM alpine:3.7

...

RUN apk add --update ca-certificates \
 && apk add --update -t deps curl\
 && curl -L https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/${KUBE_LATEST_VERSION}/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl -o /usr/local/bin/kubectl \
 && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/kubectl \
 && apk del --purge deps \
 && apk add --update jq su-exec unzip curl bash openldap-clients \
 && rm /var/cache/apk/* \
 && mkdir -p $FORGEROCK_HOME \
 && addgroup -g 11111 forgerock \
 && adduser -s /bin/bash -h "$FORGEROCK_HOME" -u 11111 -D -G forgerock forgerock
```

To change it to run off of RHEL 7 (my changes below)

```
FROM ubi7-stigd:7.6

...

# Install epel, so we can install jq later
RUN rpm --import http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7 \
&& yum install -y --disableplugin=subscription-manager https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm 

# Install other stuff
RUN yum -y --disableplugin=subscription-manager update \
 && yum install -y --disableplugin=subscription-manager jq su-exec unzip curl bash openldap-clients ca-certificates deps \
 && curl -L https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/${KUBE_LATEST_VERSION}/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl -o /usr/local/bin/kubectl \
 && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/kubectl \
 && mkdir -p $FORGEROCK_HOME \
 && groupadd -g 11111 forgerock \
 && useradd -m -s /bin/bash -d "$FORGEROCK_HOME" -u 11111 -g forgerock -G root forgerock
```

The container builds just fine (although it complains about not being able to find "su-exec" and "deps"). But when I upload this image to my OpenShift and run it via an OpenAM pod, the container fails to start, timing out after 10 minutes. The events show that the container started, and logs only show 2 lines, saying it timed out after 10 minutes.

Anyone know what the issue might be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to install the "nc" package, as one of the .sh files uses nc.